# Adding Factor Scores to the Data Set in R using cbind

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am having difficulties adding factor scores to the original data set. It is not a difficult procedure at all, as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842216/adding-factor-scores-to-the-original-dataset). However, in my case, I receive the following error to the below code:

```
fa <- factanal(data, factors=2, rotation="promax", scores="regression")

data <- cbind(data, fa$scores)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 889, 851
```

It would be no surprise to receive this error, if the row numbers really differed, but when I type "fa$scores" and hit enter, R displays all of the 889 rows. The dim function still returns 851 though:

```
dim(fa$scores)
[1] 851   2
```

Can you please clarify for me why I am receiving this error, and if possible, what I can do to add the factor scores to the data successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check if your data have missing values.  BTW, the `mtcars` data in the link works fine for me.

Comment: I have also successfully worked the same code on other data sets, so the code is fine. So there should be something about this data set. If missing data are the culprit, how should I modify my code?

Comment: Check your dataset for NA using `is.na`

Comment: I checked it using `summary`, and yes, one of the indicators has 38 of its observations  missing.

Comment: You can try this `i1 <- !is.na(data$yourcolumn); fa <- factanal(data[i1,], factors=2, rotation="promax", scores="regression"); cbind(data[i1,], fa)`

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fa$scores` returns a matrix with rownames that you can use to join/merge the data together.

First, make sure `data` has rownames. If not, give it dummy names like:

```
rownames(data) <- 1:nrow(data)
```

Then run `fa <- factanal(...)`, and convert `fa$scores` to a data frame of factor scores. E.g.,

```
fs <- data.frame(fa$scores)
```

Then, add a `rowname` column to both your original data and `fs`:

```
data$rowname <- rownames(data)
fs$rowname   <- rownames(fs)
```

Then left join to data (using dplyr package):

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(data, fs, by = "rowname)
```